# [Vue.js 2][Google Places API] How to fix this error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPlacePredictions' of null"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-places-api

I would like to receive a boost as I have been stuck on this issue for quite some time. Thank you very much for your precious time.

**Goal :**

I would like to solve a problem. The problem is this error message in the console:

[image]

**Results:**

On a page where I use it, a redirect is done and redirects me to another page where I use it but I am no longer able to use the tool. It no longer offers me anything and shows me this error above in the console.

However, if I refresh the page (hard reload) or click on another page then click back to the profile settings page, then it works fine.

**User flow**

When a user signs up, he/she gets to fill a form (on a vue.js component) as part of an "onboarding" flow. On that specific form, the user is asked to add a place (via the v-autocomplete). To do so, I'm using the code (see below) under the script section of that component.

When the user is done, he is redirected to his/her profile settings page (again, another vue.js component) where he/she can again edit the place via the v-autocomplete. To do so, I'm using exactly the the code below(see below)under the script section of that component.

Note. Hence, the app vue.js create twice a google map instance.

**My code :**

The v-autocomplete :

```
<v-autocomplete
v-model="userPrefs.prefPlace"
:items="searchResults"
:search-input.sync="location"
hide-no-data
hide-selected
:placeholder="userPrefs.prefPlace"
item-text="Description"
item-value="API"
:error-messages="placeErrors"
@blur="$v.userPrefs.prefPlace.$touch()"
required: true
outlined
></v-autocomplete>
```

The metaInfo() :

```
metaInfo() {
  return {
    script: [
      {
        src: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.VUE_APP_FB_APIKEY}&libraries=places`,
        async: true,
        defer: true,
        callback: () => this.MapsInit() // will declare it in methods
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

The watch :

```
watch: {
  location(newValue) {
    this.timeOutID = debounce(() => {
      if (newValue) {
        this.service.getPlacePredictions(
          {
            input: this.location,
            types: ["(regions)"],
            componentRestrictions: { country: "be" }
          },
          this.displaySuggestions
        );
      }
    }, this.timeOutID, 500);
  }
}
```

The method MapsInit() and displaySuggestions() :

```
methods: {
  MapsInit() {
    this.service = new window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  },
  displaySuggestions(predictions, status) {
    if (status !== window.google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      this.searchResults = [];
      return;
    }
    this.searchResults = predictions.map(prediction => prediction.description);
  }
};
```

So, would you know where the problem is coming from? If you are missing anything, please let me know, thank you!

Comment: might want to look into @googlemaps/js-api-loader for dynamically add the maps api scripts correctly https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the Google Places script is not loaded (via the meta callback to `MapsInit()`) by the time the `location` watcher is called, so `this.service` is still its initial value (`null`).

One option is to load the script earlier in the app's lifecycle (e.g., in the `App` component, or within the `head` tag of `index.html`).

Another option is to conditionally render the `v-autocomplete` based on `service` so that the `location` watcher is only called when `service` is actually set:

```html
<v-autocomplete v-if="service" :search-input.sync="location">
```

*This assumes `<v-autocomplete>` is the only source of change to `location`.*

Comment: Hello tony19, thank you for your reply.

I tried the first solution but it doesn't work. I put the metaInfo and the MapsInit () method in app.vue but nothing helps, it doesn't work ...

Do you have any details or other potential solutions?

Again a big thank you to you. :)

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction? It's possible that it didn't work because of how you implemented it.